# Many-to-many relationship: How to decide where to place inverse=true with XML Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I was reading about inverse = true in one-to-many relation and was actually wondering where to set that property to true in a many-to-many relationship.
I know inverse is to point which entity/table is the owner of the relationship. In a one-to-many sitation this is actually quite simple. Buy how do you point a side in a many-to-many relation? Or is it not necessary?

Can you point both sides? Or do you have to choose one side? How do you actually decide which side that is?
If i think according to the owner of the relationship i think both sets have to set inverse=true because they both aren't the owner of relationship. But actually the other isn't the owner either. It's the table UsersTargets that is the owner. 
Someone that is able to get me out of my mysery?

E.g.: A user can have many awards. 
Note: It isn't necessary to know how many users have a specific award. So maybe i should make my model different? Anyway my code till now:

Domain:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    ...
    public virtual ISet<Award> Awards { get; set; }
}

public class Award : Entity
{
    ...
    public virtual ISet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<-User.hbm.xml->
<set name="Awards" table="UsersAwards" cascade="all">
    <key column="UserId"/>
    <many-to-many class="Award" column="AwardId"/>
</set>

<-Award.hbm.xml->
<set name="Users" table="UsersAwards" cascade="all">
    <key column="AwardId"/>
    <many-to-many class="User" column="UserId"/>
</set>
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly one side of the relationship should **not** be marked `inverse`.  That means that if you decide to remove the `Award.Users` property from your model, just make sure that `Users.Awards` is not marked `inverse`.

If you leave both collections in your model, and you use code like this to add / remove associations...

```
public class User
{
    public virtual void Add(Award award)
    {
        award.Users.Add(this);
        Awards.Add(award);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(Award award)
    {
        Awards.Remove(award);
        award.Users.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

... then it doesn't really matter which side you put `inverse` on - just make sure one side has it and the other side doesn't.

Comment: Thx for this great answer. Contains everything I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the side you don't use for updating as `inverse`.

In your case, you probably add Awards to a User, not users to an Award. Therefore, `Award.UserAwards` would be `inverse`

Of course if you *do* add users to the award instead, just reverse what I just said.